# When I try to run through an array, the array behaves like a set, by which I mean that if I put two equal values in, the program crashes

Tags: arrays, angularjs, set

I am doing a AngularJS program, in which I want to run through an array. Here is my program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Array: {{t}}</p>
    <span style="margin:1px;background-color:cyan;" ng-repeat="x in names">
        {{x}}
    <span>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
//    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Ellen", "Tobias", "Linus", "Poul", "Peter"]; 
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Emil", "Tobias", "Linus", "Poul", "Peter"]; 
$scope.t = angular.isArray($scope.names);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I use the upper version of $scope.names, it works. When I take the lower one, it crashes. Both of them are arrays, according to isArray, so why doesn't it work?

Very confused.

Poul

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat does not support two equal values in the same array, you should use objects with a unique identifier, like this:

```
$scope.names = [{id: 0, name: 'Emil'}, {id: 1, name: 'Emil'}];
```

or you can use `track by` as shown in the following example.
More information about ngRepeat and $index property [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#ngRepeat-arguments)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["Emil", "Emil", "Tobias", "Linus", "Poul", "Peter"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Array: {{t}}</p>
    <!-- $index: This special property tracks the collection items by their index -->
    <span style="margin:1px;background-color:cyan;" ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
        {{x}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raxel. That never did occur to me. So far, I have not encountered anything I couldn't do easier in standard Javascript. I am quickly learning to hate AngularJS. :)